# Python: installing psychopy audiolib

Tags: python, psychopy, pyo

I'm really sorry if this is a stupid question, but here it is.

I'm using Python and I've installed psychopy via anaconda command prompt in class. Now I want to use psychopy sound functions. So I tried to import sound, but get that there's no API found and that I should install pyo or pygame, which I tried to do in the anaconda command prompt, but that doesn't work either. 
Since I'm not familiar working with this kind of things, so I really have no idea how to solve this. I hope someone can help. I've tried looking on the internet, but can't find any solutions there either.

Answer (score 0):

Both `pygame` and `pyo` cannot be installed with `pip`. You need to download them from external links and install manually.

- pygame: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
- pyo: http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/download.html

**@edit** Note that those packages will only work with 32-bit Python 2.7, so if you're using a 64-bit version of Python or Python 3.x you won't be able to use them.

Comment: I installed pyo, but how should I import it in Python?

Comment: simple `import pyo` should be sufficient assuming that you installed `pyo` in your anaconda distribution

Comment: I installed it in Anaconda, but when I try import pyo, it gives me the following error: import pyo 

  File "<ipython-input-4-810eca0a5490>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyo

  File "C:\Users\Ineke\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyo.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pyolib.analysis as analysis

  File "C:\Users\Ineke\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyolib\analysis.py", line 30, in <module>
    from _core import *

  File "C:\Users\Ineke\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyolib\_core.py", line 32, in <module>
    from _pyo import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing.

Comment: what version of `python` are you using? 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 for 64 bits, I installed this from pyo: pyo_0.7.7_py2.7_setup.exe : Windows (Win 7 to 10), python 2.7, 32-bit from http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: note that those packages will only work with 32-bit `python 2.7`, so if you're using a 64-bit version of `python` or `python 3.x` you won't be able to use them